# JAXB: get Object from DB by one of it field from xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

I think that I have a trivial problem but cant find solution.
I have Class with some fields of another Classes. In XML I have one of fields from "Another Class". How can I get Another Class object by this field?
I Using SpringBoot.

Short example (Main class - Profile, Another class - Country):

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profiles>
    <profile id="1001">
        ...
        <nationality>US</nationality>
        ...
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Main class

```
@Entity
@Table
@XmlRootElement(name = "profile")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Profile {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "numericISOCode")
@XmlElement(name = "nationality")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CountryISO2Adapter.class)
private Country nationality;
...
```

Country class

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "alpha2ISO", columnNames = {"alpha2ISO"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "alpha3ISO", columnNames = {"alpha3ISO"})})
public class Country {
    private String nameENG;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String alpha2ISO;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 3)
    private String alpha3ISO;
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 3)
    private int numericISOCode;
...
```

Adapter

```
@Component
public class CountryISO2Adapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Country> {
    @Autowired
    private Service service;
    @Override
    public Country unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return service.getCountryByISO2(v).orElse(null);
    }
....
```

Service

```
@Service
public final class Service {
...
    private final CountryRepository countryRepository;
...
public Optional<Country> getCountryByISO2 (String iso2){
        return countryRepository.findByAlpha2ISO(iso2);
}
```

I tried get it from Adapter.class where I want looking it by means of methods @Service class and @Repository, but in Adapter class than I need link of bean @Servise class but @Autowired not worked in this case (may be @XmlJavaTypeAdapter get "new CountryISO2Adapter()" and it can't using bean) - I have null in my Service field in Adapter class;

May be that's wrong way? How make this correctly?

Global target - create object Profile.class with field Country.class, however Country.class object I must get from DB (but not create).

I'm sure it's a often task.

Thanks a lot for your advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like not good idea to mix dto and entity classes. In my opinion, the better solution is to create two separate classes: dto class with xml annotations and entity class with jpa annotations and convert them into another through separate converter class which will be a spring component and  autowired countryRepository to find necessary value

Comment: I'll try follow your advice. Thanks a lot.